# How to replace months in dates to specific month?

Tags: excel

I have a list of dates from different months and I need to replace the months with specific month (December in this case).

I tried to convert date format to show month in words e.g 01 for Jan. Then, used replace wizard to replace Jan to Dec. But it failed.

```
For example:
Current Date  Expected Date
18/01/2018    18/12/2018
20/02/2018    20/12/2018
31/03/2018    31/12/2018
04/04/2018    04/12/2018
19/05/2019    19/12/2018
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the date are true dates then:

```
=DATE(YEAR(A2),12,DAY(A2))
```

[image]